# Eckmann-Hilton for $A_{\infty}$-spaces?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Suppose I have a grouplike $A_{\infty}$-space $G$ that carries an *additional structure* as a topological group (which does not coincide with the $H$-space structure of the $A_{\infty}$-part). Denote the $H$-space multiplication by $*$ and the group multiplication by $\cdot$ and suppose that 
$$
(a*b) \cdot (c *d) = (a \cdot c) * (b \cdot d) 
$$
also known as the Eckmann-Hilton condition holds (equality, no "up to homotopy" here). Moreover, the identity of the group is a homotopy unit for the $H$-space structure.

> Is this enough to deduce that $BG$
>   coincides with the space $B(G_{*})$,
>   i.e. that the classifying space of the
>   topological group is (up to homotopy
>   of course) the delooping of the
>   $A_{\infty}$-space? Do I get homotopy
>   commutativity as well?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

EDIT: Here is a *counterexample* to the stated question.

I'm going to start with a topological group $G$ which is a product of Eilenberg-Mac Lane spaces.  Specifically, I'm going to choose $G \simeq K(\mathbb{Z},2) \times K(\mathbb{Z},7)$.  The Dold-Thom theorem allows me to actually construct this as an abelian topological group: I take a based CW-complex with $H_2 = \mathbb{Z}$, $H_7 = \mathbb{Z}$, and other (reduced) homology groups zero (e.g. $S^2 \vee S^7$).  Then I take the free topological abelian group on it, and this has the homotopy groups I want.

- The classifying space of $G$ using this multiplication is a $K(\mathbb{Z},3) \times K(\mathbb{Z},8)$.
- $G$ has a unique H-space structure.  Because Eilenberg-Mac Lane spaces represent cohomology, $[G \times G, G]$ is $H^2(G \times G) \times H^7(G \times G)$.  A calculation with the Kunneth formula tells you that the restrictions to each factor makes the map
  $$[G \times G, G] \to [G,G] \times [G,G]$$
  into an isomorphism.  Thus, up to homotopy there is a unique binary multiplication that's homotopy unital; the group multiplication on $G$ is a representative.
- As a result, if I construct any other $A_\infty$-structure on $G$, the binary multiplication is homotopic to the multiplication of $G$.  Since $A_\infty$-structures are insensitive to such a change by homotopy (yes, this is handwaving) I could equally well assume that the $A_\infty$-structure starts with the multiplication of $G$.  Because $G$ is abelian, this satisfies the interchange law.
- Since $A_\infty$-structures pass along homotopy equivalences, it suffices for me to find a space $Y$ and a homotopy equivalence $G \to \Omega Y$ where $Y$ is not $K(\mathbb{Z},3) \times K(\mathbb{Z},8)$.
- There is a map $f: K(\mathbb{Z},3) \to K(\mathbb{Z},9)$ classifying the cohomology operation $x \mapsto x^3$ (which is nontrivial, and 2-torsion).  I'm going to let $Y$ be the homotopy fiber of $f$.  Then $\Omega Y$ is the homotopy fiber of a map $\Omega f: K(\mathbb{Z},2) \to K(\mathbb{Z},8)$ which is 2-torsion, and hence $\Omega f$ is trivial. Therefore $\Omega Y$ is homotopy equivalent to the homotopy fiber of the trivial map, and is a product homotopy equivalent to $G$.
- The map $f$ is the first k-invariant in the Postnikov tower of $Y$, and is nontrivial, so $Y$ is not a product of Eilenberg-Mac Lane spaces.

An exercise for the reader who is not in bed right now, for whatever reason, is to trace through why several simpler choices of cohomology operation (e.g. $Sq^2: H^2 \to H^4$) don't make this argument work.

---

Below follows my original post.  I assumed that the interchange law held for the entire $A_\infty$-structure, meaning that for any of the $n$-ary operations $m_n$ we would have
$$
m_n(x_1 \ast y_1, \ldots, x_n \ast y_n) = m_n(x_1, \ldots, x_n) \ast m_n(y_1, \ldots, y_n).
$$
However, the question only says that the H-space structure itself satisfies the interchange law, and not the higher coherences.

The Eckmann-Hilton condition implies that you can take classifying spaces twice, and the order of taking classifying spaces doesn't matter.  You can write $BBG$ for this iterated classifying space.  Both $B(G)$ and $B(G_*)$ are grouplike, and so the group completion theorem implies that the natural maps $B(G) \to \Omega BBG$ and $B(G_*) \to \Omega BBG$ are weak equivalences.  Thus, under the standard types of point-set assumptions on $G$, both classifying spaces are weakly equivalent.

In addition, this implies that, because $G$ is grouplike, it is weakly equivalent to the 2-fold loop space $\Omega^2 BBG$ with either H-space structure, and hence both multiplications are homotopy commutative.

This is related to work of Brun, Fiedorowicz, and Vogt in "On the multiplicative structure of topological Hochschild homology." ([preprint version here](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0410367))  They show that the "tensor product" of the associative operad with the little $n$-cubes operad is weakly equivalent to the little $(n+1)$-cubes operad.  This means that having an associative multiplication and an $A_\infty$-multiplication is, up to homotopy equivalence, basically the same as having an $E_2$-multiplication.

Comment: Thanks Tyler! I think the higher compatibility conditions also hold in the case I am considering. That counterexample is very enlightening.

Comment: Shouldn't it be possible to deduce the existence of homotopy inverses from the Eckmann-Hilton condition as well? We know that G is a group: Can we run through the Eckmann-Hilton clock (up to homotopy) to deduce that homotopy inverses exist for the H-space structure?

Comment: @Ulrich: Yes.  An H-space structure on G is the same as a lift of the functor $X \mapsto [X,G]$ to monoids; it factors through a group-valued functor if and only if a homotopy inverse exists.  Since you're assuming the H-space structure is the same on both ends, you do have that homotopy commutativity and a homotopy inverse exist for your `$A_\infty$`-structure.

Comment: Thanks again. Eckmann-Hilton really seems to be a "buy one, get one free"-condition :-)! 

Comment: One last question about your second argument: You say, that both $BG$ and $BG_*$ are grouplike. But I only know this for G itself. Why is this true for $BG$ and $BG_*$?

Comment: $BG$ is always grouplike because it is connected.  An H-space which is a CW-complex for which $\pi_0$ is a group is always grouplike.  You can check this as follows. The "shear" map $H \times H \to H \times H$ given by $(x,y) \mapsto (xy,y)$ is a homotopy equivalence, because: (a) it is an isomorphism on `$\pi_0$` (b) using the multiplication makes it suffices to check the identity component (c) using the projection to second factor, the shear map is a self-map of the fibration of connected spaces `$H_e \times H_e \to H_e$` which is the identity on both base and fiber, hence is a weak equiv.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer and the proof. I feel a little stupid now: I actually knew that theorem, but somehow was too blind to think about the connectivity of $BG$ :-).